# pass number of item to be formatted in Python string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, string-formatting

I've a string which uses a List element.

```
alist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
s = "my amazing string %s" % ('-'.join(alist))
```

this will return `my amazing string a-b-c-d-e"`

now what I want is to pass a number which can tell me that you should join only these many elements.

for example ~ something similar if I want to join only first 3 elements

`s = "my amazing string %<3>s" % ('-'.join(alist))`

and output would be
`"my amazing string a-b-c"`

the main string (`"my amazing string %s"`) I'm getting from somewhere else. and I've this list.

is there any other method like using `.format()`

PS: Again I can't use list slice alist[:3] because I dont know this number.

`s = "my amazing string %<3>s" % ('-'.join(alist[:3]))`

this number would be in the main string which needs to be populate by this list. only this string should contains this information that how many items we need from this list

Answer (score 3):

use slicing

```
print '-'.join(alist[:3])
```

use regex

```
>>> alist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> import re
>>> s = "my amazing string %<3>s"
>>> times = int(re.search(r'%<(\d+)>s', s).group(1))
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=\%)<\d+>(?=s)', '', s) % '-'.join(alist[:times])
'my amazing string a-b-c'
```

Comment: @xyz, what do you mean by keyword arguments?